# Reading Large Binary File in c++

Tags: c++, oracle

I'm trying to read binary file(.dat format) of size around 360kb and inserting it into blob column of oracle database. The issue i'm facing is my code doesn't insert complete file but is inserting only part of the file.I wanted to know if there is any way to read large binary files.This code works fine for small binary files... Here is my code....

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <occi.h>

using namespace oracle::occi;
using namespace std;


int main () {

Environment *env;
Connection *conn;
Statement *stmt;


env = Environment::createEnvironment (Environment::DEFAULT); 
try{
    conn = env -> createConnection("oracle", "oracle", "xxxxx"); 
    stmt = conn -> createStatement("insert into velodyne(name,info) VALUES(:x,:y)"); 
    stmt -> setInt(1,112);

    streampos size;
    char* memblock;
    ifstream fileIn ("filename", ios::in|ios::binary|ios::ate); 
        if (fileIn.is_open())
            {
                size = fileIn.tellg();
                cout<<"size of the file is:"<< size <<endl;
                memblock = new char [size];
                //cout<<"size of the memblock is:"<< memblock <<endl;
                fileIn.seekg (0, ios::beg);
                fileIn.read (memblock, size);
                fileIn.close(); 
            }

    Bytes *Data = new Bytes((unsigned char*) memblock, size); 

    stmt -> setBytes(2, *Data); 
    stmt -> executeUpdate();
    conn->commit();
    delete[] memblock;
        conn->terminateStatement (stmt);
}
    catch (SQLException ea)
     {
    cout<<ea.what();            
    }

Environment::terminateEnvironment (env);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you please check what `fileIn.good()` and `fileIn.gcount()` return, after the `fileIn.read()` but before `fileIn.close()`?

Comment: If your database API has functions for loading blob data, use that.

Comment: @mauve fileIn.gcount() is returning the actual file size that i'm trying to insert but the blob column is showing only part of file after execution

Comment: @user4215256 are you sure that the database doesn't have a blob size limit? what value is `gcount()` returning and what size is the final blob?

Comment: @mauve yeah i'm sure about blob size limit. We can insert maximum of 4GB in blob. gcount() value is 360kb(complete file size) but the blob has only 33kb after insertion...I tried to insert breakpoints and it shows 0xcccccccc Bad ptr at memblock....